# history.push not working react router dom

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello guys I have a problem with useHistory(); (react-router-dom);

my history.push is not working, I need to refresh the browser for him work.

I am new with react and,

what I am doing wrong?

Can anyone help me with it??
sx

code below:

```
const history = useHistory();
  const handleSignIn = useCallback(
    async data => {
      try {
        await getToken(data.username, data.password);

        history.push('/dashboard');
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Yup.ValidationError) {
          const errors = getValidationErrors(err);

          if (formRef.current) {
            formRef.current.setErrors(errors);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    [getToken, history],
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <h1>Faça seu login</h1>
        <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
          <Input name="username" placeholder="Usuário" />
          <Input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
          <Button type="submit">Entrar</Button>
        </Form>
```

index of routes below :

```
import React from 'react';

import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from './Route';

import Register from '../pages/Register';
import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from '../pages/SignUp';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isPrivate />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

this is my code of private routes:

```
export default function Route({
  isPrivate = false,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <ReactDOMRoute
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return isPrivate === !!user ? (
          <Component />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: isPrivate ? '/' : '/dashboard',
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

> My App.js below:

```
import Routes from './routes';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AppProvider>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your routing component logic. I don't see anything overtly wrong with the `history.push`, so maybe it is an issue with trying to match a route's path attribute.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated my question !!

Comment: Are your `Route`s and whatever that top component is all rendered within a `Router` component? It should wrap your app somewhere near the app root.

Comment: @DrewReese I put my App.js in the question.

Comment: Well, your `Route` component is interesting, but I don't see any red flags there. What is `ReactDOMRoute`? I can't find any documentation on that from react-router-dom. Is it possible for you to reproduce this issue in a *running* codesandbox that can be lived debugged?

Comment: @DrewReese I import Route as ReactDOMRoute from react-router-dom

Comment: I see, ok, then the router and route code seems sound. Can you try creating a codesandbox then?